# SQL Server 2012 CHECK constraint not firing on UPDATE or DELETE statements

Tags: triggers, sql-server-2012, check-constraints

I'm trying to perform data validation on a table, and I need to check across multiple rows and columns. Basically I want to make sure that for any given tool, at least one version exists that is flagged as either the Active version, or the Beta version.

The only way I could think to check this is through a user-defined scalar function, and a `CHECK` constraint that calls the function. I was able to create the function that returns what I expect (0 if OK, 1 if not) and it works... but *only* on an `INSERT`. When I perform an `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement, the check constraint doesn't fail, so I can end up with bad data in either case.

Here's a sample of the table and function I'm using.

```
CREATE TABLE VersionTest(VersionID int NOT NULL, ToolID int NOT NULL, IsActiveVersion bit NOT NULL, IsBetaVersion bit NOT NULL)
GO

ALTER TABLE VersionTest ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_VersionTest_IsActiveVersion]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsActiveVersion]
GO

ALTER TABLE VersionTest ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_VersionTest_IsBetaVersion]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsBetaVersion]
GO

CREATE FUNCTION fn_ValidateVersionTest(@toolID int) RETURNS SMALLINT
AS
      BEGIN
      IF (@toolID = -1)
        BEGIN
          RETURN 0
        END
      ELSE
        BEGIN
            IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM VersionTest
                       WHERE ToolID = @toolID
                       GROUP BY ToolID, IsActiveVersion, IsBetaVersion
                       HAVING (SUM(CASE WHEN IsActiveVersion = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
                               SUM(CASE WHEN IsBetaVersion = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > 0)
              RETURN 0
        END
        RETURN 1      
    END
GO

ALTER TABLE VersionTest WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_VersionTest] CHECK  (([dbo].[fn_ValidateVersionTest]([ToolID])=(0)))
GO
ALTER TABLE VersionTest CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_VersionTest]
GO
```

The following INSERT statements work just fine.

```
INSERT INTO VersionTest (ToolID, VersionID, IsActiveVersion, IsBetaVersion)
VALUES (1, 1, 1, 0)

INSERT INTO VersionTest (ToolID, VersionID, IsActiveVersion, IsBetaVersion)
VALUES (1, 2, 0, 0)
```

As expected, this INSERT statement fails:

```
INSERT INTO VersionTest (ToolID, VersionID, IsActiveVersion, IsBetaVersion)
VALUES (2, 1, 0, 0)
```

However, the following UPDATE and DELETE statements aren't failing when I expected them to:

```
UPDATE VersionTest 
SET IsActiveVersion = 0, IsBetaVersion = 0
WHERE VersionID = 1

DELETE VersionTest WHERE VersionID = 1
```

Is there another way I should be doing this? Do I have to use triggers instead?

Comment: See [MSSQL: Update statement avoiding the CHECK constraint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059929/mssql-update-statement-avoiding-the-check-constraint)

Comment: Please stop combing check constraints and UDFs. [Several articles here explain how wrong this can go](https://sqlblog.org/search/SearchResults.aspx?q=check+constraint+function).

Answer (score 2):

We can force the check on update on this way.
Lets suppose you have a table like this

```
create table UserTest(Id int, IsEnabled bit, [GroupId] int)
```

Now, we want to check only 1 user is enable by `[GroupId]`.

Usually the constraint will look something like

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserTest] ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_OnlyOneEnabled  CHECK (dbo.checkOnlyOne(GroupId)=1)
```

This constraint will not be triggered over the record been updated until you update the `GroupId`.
So, we have to force the constraint to validate the IsEnabled column by doing

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserTest] ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_OnlyOneEnabled  CHECK (dbo.checkOnlyOne(GroupId, IsEnabled )=1)
```

No matters if you use or not the IsEnabled value into the function.

Comment: looks like my scenario, you have to pass extra parameter even if function doesn't use it