# Constraint with multiple tables. UDF?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, constraints, user-defined-functions

I have two tables: table A and table B. These two tables are linked with a primary key in A and a foreign key in B.

Table A:

```
CREATE TABLE [BIO].[table_A](
    [table_A_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  
    [type_id] [nvarchar](2) NOT NULL    
CONSTRAINT [PK_table_A] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [table_A_id] ASC
))
```

Table B:

```
CREATE TABLE [BIO].[table_B](
    [table_B_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [table_A_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [analysis_id] [tinyint] NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT [PK_table_B] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [table_B_id] ASC
))

ALTER TABLE [BIO].[table_B] WITH CHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_table_B_table_A] FOREIGN KEY([table_A_id])
REFERENCES [BIO].[table_A] ([table_A_id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [BIO].[table_B] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_table_B_table_A]
GO
```

Table B must contain only specific values according to the values in table A.
For example, if I have BL in table A, I can only have 1 or 3 in table B; if I have ST in table A, I can only have 2 or 4 in table B.

I have setup a bridge table which defines these combinations: BL→1 or 3, ST→2 or 4.

Bridge table:

```
CREATE TABLE [QRY].[bridge_table](
    [type_id] [nvarchar](2) NOT NULL,
    [analysis_id] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_bridge_table] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [type_id] ASC,
    [analysis_id] ASC
))
```

I am currently using one constraint per table to be sure that any insert or update is correct according to the combinations defined in the bridge table. These two constraints are based on UDFs.

Constraint on table B:

```
ALTER TABLE [BIO].[Table_B] WITH CHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_chkAnalysisType] 
CHECK (([QRY].[TypeAnalysisMatch_table_B]([table_A_id])>(0)))
GO
```

UDF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [QRY].[TypeAnalysisMatch_table_B] (@table_A_id int)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN
    (
    SELECT
        Count(BIO.table_A.table_A_id) AS cnt_rec
    FROM
        QRY.bridge_table
        INNER JOIN BIO.table_A ON QRY.bridge_table.type_id = BIO.table_A.type_id
        INNER JOIN BIO.table_B ON 
                QRY.bridge_table.analysis_id = BIO.table_B.analysis_id
            AND BIO.table_A.table_A_id = BIO.table_B.table_A_id
    WHERE
        BIO.table_A.table_A_id = @table_A_id
    )
END
```

It works well for the `INSERT` but not consistently for the `UPDATE`. Moreover, as I read that UDFs in constraints should be avoided, I am looking for a better solution.

What would be an efficient alternative to these constraints?

Comment: Please edit your question to include ddl+dml for some sample data. Also, include the UDF you are currently using.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: Question edited with data definition. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, having `UDF` in `CHECK` constraints can be tricky and some `UPDATE` statements may bypass the check:

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tibor_karaszi/archive/2009/12/17/be-careful-with-constraints-calling-udfs.aspx

[MSSQL: Update statement avoiding the CHECK constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059929/mssql-update-statement-avoiding-the-check-constraint)

As you can see in that SO question the answer recommended to use trigger for the check. Writing a correct efficient trigger is also not an easy task.

---

I assume that your `bridge_table` contains this data:

```
type_id    analysis_id
BL         1
BL         3
ST         2
ST         4
```

I would set up these constraints using only foreign keys, without UDF. It would require some (minimal) duplication of the data, though. I assume that real `table_A` and `table_B` have more columns than this example.

**1.** In `table_A` include `type_id` in the primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE [table_A](
    [table_A_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [type_id] [nvarchar](2) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_table_A] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [table_A_id] ASC,
    [type_id] ASC
))
```

**2.** Add a column `type_id` to the `table_B`. Yes, the same column as you already have in `table_A`. This is that duplication of data that I mentioned above:

```
CREATE TABLE [table_B](
    [table_B_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [table_A_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [type_id] [nvarchar](2) NOT NULL,
    [analysis_id] [tinyint] NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT [PK_table_B] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [table_B_id] ASC
))
```

**3.** Make foreign key that links `table_B` with `table_A` on two columns `(table_A_id, type_id)`:

```
ALTER TABLE [table_B] WITH CHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_table_B_table_A] FOREIGN KEY([table_A_id], [type_id])
REFERENCES [table_A] ([table_A_id], [type_id])
```

This constraint guarantees that `type_id` values that are duplicated in `table_B` will be consistent with original values from `table_A`.

**4.** Make foreign key that links `table_B` with `bridge_table` again on two columns `(type_id, analysis_id)`:

```
ALTER TABLE [table_B] WITH CHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_table_B_bridge_table] FOREIGN KEY([type_id], [analysis_id])
REFERENCES [bridge_table] ([type_id], [analysis_id])
```

**5.** Now you can test that everything works as intended.

Add few rows to `table_A`:

```
INSERT INTO [table_A] ([type_id]) 
VALUES ('BL'), ('BL'), ('ST'), ('ZZ');

table_A_id    type_id
1             BL
2             BL
3             ST
4             ZZ
```

Try to insert valid data into `table_B`:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_B] ([table_A_id],[type_id],[analysis_id])
VALUES (1,'BL',1)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_B] ([table_A_id],[type_id],[analysis_id])
VALUES (1,'BL',3)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_B] ([table_A_id],[type_id],[analysis_id])
VALUES (2,'BL',3)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_B] ([table_A_id],[type_id],[analysis_id])
VALUES (3,'ST',2)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_B] ([table_A_id],[type_id],[analysis_id])
VALUES (3,'ST',2)

table_B_id    table_A_id    type_id    analysis_id
1             1             BL         1
2             1             BL         3
3             2             BL         3
4             3             ST         2
5             3             ST         2
```

Try to insert invalid data:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_B] ([table_A_id],[type_id],[analysis_id])
VALUES (3,'ST',1)

The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_table_B_bridge_table". 
The conflict occurred in database "tempdb", table "dbo.bridge_table".
The statement has been terminated.
```

Which means, that `ST` can't have `analysis_id=1`

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_B] ([table_A_id],[type_id],[analysis_id])
VALUES (3,'BL',1)

The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_table_B_table_A". 
The conflict occurred in database "tempdb", table "dbo.table_A".
The statement has been terminated.
```

Which means, that the row in `table_A` with `table_A_id=3` doesn't have `BL` in `type_id`.

Foreign keys would keep checking data consistency for all `UPDATE` statements as well:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[table_B]
SET [type_id] = 'ST'
WHERE [table_B_id] = 1

The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_table_B_table_A". 
The conflict occurred in database "tempdb", table "dbo.table_A".
The statement has been terminated.

UPDATE [dbo].[table_B]
SET [analysis_id] = 2
WHERE [table_B_id] = 1

The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_table_B_bridge_table". 
The conflict occurred in database "tempdb", table "dbo.bridge_table".
The statement has been terminated.
```

But this one works:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[table_B]
SET [analysis_id] = 3
WHERE [table_B_id] = 1

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: For (3) I'd possibly recommend "ON UPDATE CASCADE" so that updates in table `A` "just work". I might also recommend renaming table `B` and creating a view called `B` querying the old table that doesn't have the `type_id` column. Finally, an `INSERT` trigger on that view would ensure the correct value is inserted. The application continues to work with `A` and `B` and they look the same as before, and so the duplication is "hidden".

Comment: @Vladimir Baranov  Thanks, this is exactly what i was looking for. The duplication of data is not an issue in my case especially with a nvarachr(2). I had to adapt your code using an unique index instead of a multicolumn primary key at step 1, but it works beautifully.